# Antd - Disable scroll bar in Header but not in Content in the layout

Tags: reactjs, layout, antd

I am using [Antd Layout](https://ant.design/components/layout) in my app where the Header and the Sider are fixed.
I want my content to be scrollable but I don't want the scrollbar to appear beside the Header. I couldn't find any example on how to do this and I can't seem to figure it out on my own

What I have now:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, if you want to scroll inside an area, it must has a **fixed height**.

Here, you can set `height` (or `maxHeight`) of the `<Layout/>` which is wrapping `<Header/>` and `<Content/>`. Then set fixed `height` for `<Header/>` and set `overflow: "auto"` for `<Content/>`.

[Link demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-sider-antd-undefined-forked-b1i69t?file=/demo.js)

```
<Layout hasSider>
  <Sider {/* ... */} />
  <Layout
    className="site-layout"
    style={{ marginLeft: 200, height: "100vh" }}
  >
    <Header style={{ height: 60 }} />
    <Content style={{ padding: 16, overflow: "auto" }}>
      {/* content here /*}
    </Content>
  </Layout>
</Layout>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: It looks exactly how I wanted. Thank you so much.